# BigQuery UNNEST including empty rows?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

For BigQuery, we can extract the special repeated structs using UNNEST. This works very well when you have data in the struct key and value (one of string, int or double). However, occasionally I have a struct with a key ("foo") and often with data value.string_value but not always. The following will NOT include the row when there is no string_value:

```
SELECT
  event_timestamp,
  event_params_custom.value.string_value
FROM 
  `my_database.events_*` T,
  UNNEST(T.event_params) event_params_custom
WHERE
  event_name = "some_custom_event"
  AND event_params_custom.key = "foo"
```

Is it possible to do something akin to "outer join" and include all rows even when there is no value for the key "foo"?

Comment: Can you please provide sample data?

Comment: I still haven't figured out the solution to the problem, but I have found a workaround. You can split your query into separate parts and then combine the results using a "UNION ALL". The key is then, to avoid duplicates by tweak each of the queries to only include rows where the specific key which you capture in another query, is missing: ...AND 'STOP_NO' NOT IN (SELECT key FROM UNNEST(T.event_params))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  event_timestamp,
  (SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = "foo") AS string_value
FROM 
  `my_database.events_*`
WHERE
  event_name = "some_custom_event"
```

Comment: So no need to join basically?! Thanks a lot!